# How to access class members from advice in AspectJ?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, class-members

I have this piece of code:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature;

aspect SomeAspect {
    void around(): call(void jy.run()) {
        System.out.println(>> here I want access jy's final field a<<);
    }
}
```

How to access local field of class `jy` in aspect's code?

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: AspecJ extension for Java: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `target` pointcut:

```
void around(jy t): target(t) && call(void run()) {
    System.out.println(t.someField);
}
```